# jprofiler cannot load agent archive in integration wizard

Tags: jprofiler

I am trying to create agent files on my machines while going through JProfile Integration Wizard (remote machine).

When I get to step 6 and attempt to download agent archive I get an error:

> "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

- [image: error]

And a separate questions - are JProfiler agents a) per OS or b) per OS/Java version?

Comment: You should probably show that stacktrace as text in the question itself. Images are not searchable or copyable. Please stick to a single question at a time.

Comment: I assume you are using JProfiler 10.1.x. This is a failure in the SSL connection. Do you have a proxy in between? Can you try this on a different computer?